# Can't set .NET runtime in MonoDevelop on Windows

Tags: .net, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to set the version of the .net runtime in monodevelop.

So I navigate to Tools > Options > Projects > .NET Runtimes

The only runtime visible is Microsoft.Net (Default)

I have installed 4.0, 3.5, 3.0 and 2.0

So I thought I should be able to add these versions to MonoDevelop by clicking the Add button

I'm unsure as to what I'm supposed to select.

I navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 and tried to select the folder.

I get the following error message:

```
Please provide a valid directory prefix where mono is installed (for example, /usr)
```

Is MonoDevelop only able to use the Mono implementation of .NET?

If not, why cant I add the other versions?

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop only allows you to add Mono as new runtime if you download and install Mono from

http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

What you want to fulfill is doable via Project Options where you can change Target framework to the one you want. Don't misunderstand ".NET Runtimes", as that's not what you want to change.